# How to construct function for applying filter?

Tags: functions, filters

I'm trying to modify the thumbnail sizes in a related posts plugin using a filter.

This is the code for applying the filter which is in the plugin file for displaying the front end output:

`$thumb_size = apply_filters( 'bawmrp_thumb_size', array( 100, 100 ) );`.

I tried placing the following code in my `functions.php` file but it's not working:

```
add_filter( 'bawmrp_thumb_size', 'related_posts_custom_thumbnail_size' );

function related_posts_custom_thumbnail_size () {
$custom_thumb_size = array( 200, 100 );
return $custom_thumb_size;
}
```

Comment: Where are you putting this piece of code? Where is apply_filters( 'bawmrp_thumb_size', array( 100, 100 ) ) located? Also, it seems to me you are trying to change a registered image size, right? So after changing it did you perform an upload in order to see if it's really not working?

Comment: Hi, I've updated the question to include the information you asked about.